# How to test if else condition in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to RSpec and I want to test if-else condition of a controller, I searched on the internet but the found results are not properly satisfying my search query.

Here is my rails controller:

```
class ScheduleTimeSlotsController < ApplicationController
  def get_available_schedules
    if params[:for_date].to_date==Date.today
      available_schedules=ScheduleTimeSlot.where(:doctor_id => params[:dr_id],:date=>params[:for_date].to_date,:status=>"vacant",:archive=>false).where("start_time >=?",Time.now.seconds_since_midnight).reorder(:start_time)
    else
      available_schedules=ScheduleTimeSlot.where(:doctor_id => params[:dr_id],:date=>params[:for_date].to_date,:status=>"vacant",:archive=>false).reorder(:start_time)
    end
    render :json =>{:available_schedules=>available_schedules}
  end
end
```

I'm using ruby version 2.2.4 and rails version is 4.2.0

Please guide me that how do I write RSpec for this condition, with the help of an example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your conditions depends on params so you can check your if - else conditions by passing your params once correct and next time incorrect for respective test scenario.

Comment: Your controller's code is incomplete, please attach the whole code, and only then will someone be able to write the appropriate test.

Comment: @amingilani I've now added the whole exact code, now answer me.
You can explain this condition by taking any example.

Comment: @VishalNagda don't forget to mark this question as answered, if you found the answer.

Comment: well!! this is not the exact answer. but with the help of this answer if i get the specific solution later then i will mark it as answered afterwards. please don't worry about this. i will get to you soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you've made no attempt to solve the problem yourself. Try something and ask if you run across any specific problems.

Comment: I've tried to solve it... Thanks to @amingilani to help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to run two tests for your controller. In one pass a date that is today, and one that isn't and test the responses. Here:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ScheduleTimeSlotsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #get_available_schedules when for_date is today' do
    it 'returns http success' do

    for_date = Date.today
    available_schedules = ScheduleTimeSlot.where(
      doctor_id: params[:dr_id],
      date: params[:for_date].to_date,
      status: 'vacant',
      archive: false
    ).where(
      'start_time >=?',
      Time.now.seconds_since_midnight
    ).reorder(:start_time)

      get 'get_available_schedules', for_date: for_date
      expect(response.body.available_schedules).to eq(available_schedules)
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #get_available_schedules when for_date is not today' do
    it 'returns http success' do

    for_date = Date.yesterday
    available_schedules = ScheduleTimeSlot.where(
      doctor_id: params[:dr_id], date: params[:for_date].to_date,
      status: 'vacant',
      archive: false
    ).reorder(:start_time)

      get 'get_available_schedules', for_date: for_date
      expect(response.body.available_schedules).to eq(available_schedules)
    end
  end
end
```

Disclaimer: this code is untested, since I don't have access to the actual app.